# Using the super() method in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I have to create a Square class derived from the Rectangle class using the super() method. I've been using it for other methods and when I use it in a derived method I only put

```
super().__init__()
```

but when I use it for the square method I get an error

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'x', 'y', 'width', and 'height'
```

Where would I put the 4 arguments if for a square I already put in its own initialization that it requires only 3?

I don't know if it is important but Rectangle class is derived from another class Polygon, maybe there is something I am missing?
Here's the code:

```
class Rectangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_point( (x, y) )
        self.add_point( (x + width, y) )
        self.add_point( (x + width, y + height) )
        self.add_point( (x, y + height) )


class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self,x,y,length, width):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_point( (x,y))
        self.add_point( (x+length, y))
        self.add_point( (x+length, y+ length))
        self.add_point( (x, y+length))
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling `super().__init__()` be sure to pass the appropriate arguments to it.

`super().__init__(x, y, width, height)`

**To explain:** In the context of `Square`, calling `super().__init__()` is calling `Rectangle.__init__` since it is the subclass. Then Rectangle's `__init__` calls `super.__init__()` which is calling `Polygon.__init__()`. **All** of these calls need to have the correct arguments for the init funciton they are calling.

Comment: But a square requires only 3 arguments so how would I pass 4 arguments for rectangle.

Comment: Right. A square has the _same length and width_. You might call `Square(x,y,width)` then you would call `super().__init__(x,y,width,width)`

Comment: As an aside, in the source, you have Square taking 4 args.